# How to prove $n≥3$ imples $n^2 \geq 2n + 1$ by induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I am facing some trouble figuring out this induction problem.

How I tried to do:

> **Theorem:** For all integers $n ≥ 3,$ we have $n^2 \geq 2n+1.$

Let $P(n)$ be the statement: $n^2 > 2n+1.$

1. show that $p(3)$ is true.
   When $n=3,$ $3^2 = 9$  and $2(3)+1=7,$ so $P(2)$ to be true for $n^2 > 2n+1.$

Induction Step: Suppose $P(k)$ is true for some integer $k \geq 3,$ then $k^2 > 2(k)+1.$ We wish to show that $P(k+1)$ is true, that is $(k+1)^2 > 2(k+1)+1.$ We then factor it out to be $k^2 + 2k + 1 \geq 2k+3.$ I am stuck from here. Any help would be relly nice, thanks in advance.

Comment: How about just subtracting 2k+1 on both sides of your last inequality? You then have $k^2 \geq 2$ which surely holds for all $k \geq 3$ so your induction step is true.

Comment: Without induction: $n \ge 3 \implies (n-1)^2 \ge 2 \implies n^2 \ge 2n+1$